# For a REST service, is api.domain.com more secure than domain.com/api?

Tags: javascript, security, rest, csrf

I'm considering what base URL to use for a REST web service. I have the option of using one of the following formats:

1. https://domain.com/api
2. https://api.domain.com

I'd like to make it both easy to use from client-side javascript apps and secure against forged request attacks. Is there a best practice to follow here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If domain.com is a shared domain then every part should have their own subdomain, and no one should use the main domain, that is a must for keeping all sessions separate.

If domain.com is a private domain it doesn't matter.